# Need help scraping specific span tag from webpage

Tags: html, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So here is the html code:

```
<button data-v-63a32c95="" disabled="disabled" class="bt-button bt-default" data-v-1b41da19=""><!----> <span>Sold Out</span> <!----></button>
```

I am trying to scrape the "Sold Out" from the span tag. I have tried this current code

```
wd2 = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=options)
wd2.get("https://shop.bitmain.com/product/detail?pid=00020210224195530399kqcF32sc06B9")
b = wd2.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='bt-button bt-default']//span") 
#b = wd2.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='bt-button bt-default']")
for i in b:
    print(i.text)
```

When I run this, it doesn't return anything. I've tried other beautiful soup methods such as trying to select all span tags on the page and still have had no luck. I'm pretty new to web scraping and would love some help and insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your xpath selector is right but you need to wait until the page finish rendered, use `WebDriverWait`.

```python
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

.....

# wait 10 second until element rendered
button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
             EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@class="bt-button bt-default"]//span')))
print(button.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

The elements are in the selenium webdriver elements, and you need to first extract the HTML from it before you can retrieve it's text.

```
driver_element..get_attribute("outerHTML")
```

Try this:

```
wd2 = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=options)
wd2.get("https://shop.bitmain.com/product/detail?pid=00020210224195530399kqcF32sc06B9")
b = wd2.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='bt-button bt-default']//span") 
#b = wd2.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='bt-button bt-default']")
for i in b:
    text = i.get_attribute("outerHTML")
    print(text)
```

Comment: I appreciate the help! Thank you!